# TypeScript and React issue

Tags: reactjs, firebase, jsx, firebase-hosting, tsx

Well, recently I've started using the React.js library, and now I'm trying to use it with Firebase Hosting, with the TypeScript language. But, every time I try to write some code using tsx it just doesn't work, for example:

```
import * as React from "react"; //red underline under "react"
import "./App.css";

import logo from "./logo.svg";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello</h1>; //red underline under <h1> and </h1>
  }
}

export default App;
```

that way I just can't write any jsx code here, because it always appears the issue:

```
test.tsx(1,1): error TS7026: JSX element implicitly has type 'any' because no interface 'JSX.IntrinsicElements' exists
```

Can somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you create your react application? If you used [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) you'll need to use [react-scripts-ts](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript) as your --scripts-version flag. This should install the @types packages along side React's dependencies, eliminating your problem.

Also, it should get you started with an App.tsx file as the one provided in your snippet is not a valid typescript react component (i.e. the your render() method is not public).

Happy hacking!

Comment: Well, it worked, but now there's another issue.
The generated Firebase Hosting website is pratically frozen, I mean, it doesn't update no matter what I do. I have already tried to modify the App.tsx, App.test.tsx files and even the index.html one, but none of them have changed the site.
Can you help me with this??

Comment: @BrunoOliveira it could be a number of things, have you tried accessing the site in incognito, tried clearing your cache, tried clearing the cache on DNS proxy sites such as CloudFlare if you've set that up? I've never used Firebase Hosting before so I can't really answer that one.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by reloading VSCode.
`ctrl+shift+P > Developer: Reload Window`

Comment: Idk why but thus resolved my issue. Thanks man